# Android keyEvent menu key not working

Tags: android, keyevent

Why does this code not work for me?

I  want to set `onClickListener` for hardware menu key in Android. Please help me.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu key pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

            return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: If i don't make a mistake, on emulator F2 is menu hard Key. You can check your code by press F2. OMG, your code has too much `return` statement

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch(keyCode){
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu key pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;

        default: return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

}